# Wrong oscillator frequency set by ConstantSourceNode

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am creating a synth voice which contains three oscillators as you can see in the following snippet.

```js
const ctx = new AudioContext();

const osc1 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc1.type = "sawtooth";
osc1.start();
const osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc2.type = "sawtooth";
osc2.detune.setValueAtTime(1200, ctx.currentTime);
osc2.start();
const osc3 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc3.type = "sawtooth";
osc3.detune.setValueAtTime(1900, ctx.currentTime);
osc3.start();

const gain = ctx.createGain();
gain.gain.value = 0.2;
gain.connect(ctx.destination);

osc1.connect(gain);
osc2.connect(gain);
osc3.connect(gain);

osc1.frequency.value = 160;
osc2.frequency.value = 160;
osc3.frequency.value = 160;
```

To play a melody, I would like to control the frequency of all the oscillators by one AudioParam. I found that it should be done via ConstantSourceNode. But for some reason it is now playing different frequency then I set.

```js
const ctx = new AudioContext();

const osc1 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc1.type = "sawtooth";
osc1.start();
const osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc2.type = "sawtooth";
osc2.detune.setValueAtTime(1200, ctx.currentTime);
osc2.start();
const osc3 = ctx.createOscillator();
osc3.type = "sawtooth";
osc3.detune.setValueAtTime(1900, ctx.currentTime);
osc3.start();

const gain = ctx.createGain();
gain.gain.value = 0.2;
gain.connect(ctx.destination);

osc1.connect(gain);
osc2.connect(gain);
osc3.connect(gain);

const control = ctx.createConstantSource();
control.connect(osc1.frequency);
control.connect(osc2.frequency);
control.connect(osc3.frequency);
control.start();
control.offset.value = 160;
```

I noticed that minValue and maxValue are different for oscillator's frequency AudioParam and ConstantSource's offset AudioParam. Is it somehow scaled? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you connect an AudioNode to an AudioParam the output signal of the AudioNode gets mixed with the intrinsic value of the AudioParam.

In you particular example this means that the actual frequency will be 600. The default frequency of an Oscillator is 440. This gets mixed with the value that comes from the ConstantSourceNode.

```
440 + 160 === 600
```

To achieve your desired result you can set the value of each oscillator to zero.

```
osc1.frequency.setValueAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime);
osc2.frequency.setValueAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime);
osc3.frequency.setValueAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime);
```

Here is a link to the part of the spec which describes this behavior: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audionode-connect-destinationparam-output

Answer (score 0):

The default for an OscillatorNode frequency is 440, but you're setting the default offset to 160.